# C# HttpClient response unreadable content

Tags: c#, facebook, https, dotnet-httpclient

**I solved my problem by remove the header name/value: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate**

I'm using HttpClient class to make request to Facebook. I make to request to facebook.

The first is to homepage: The result is the HTML code of Facebook homepage.

The second is login to facebook ( with headers and request body ): The result of this requert is unreadable. It's "ï¿½ï¿½|koï¿½Hvï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.ï¿½cï¿½ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½jya[vï¿½nï¿½ï¿½dï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½Dï¿½Ä²(ï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½rqï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½Øï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½/Iï¿½ï¿½X ï¿½oï¿½|ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½oï¿½sï¿½ï¿½"

If I login failed, the result must be some readable string. What am I encountering? What should i do to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please show us your code - and ideally the HTTP headers you're receiving in the response, too. Is it possible that this is just a compressed response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the content is gzipped or not and deflate it dynamically. Otherwise, just remove the Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate as you mentioned in your original question